# add an image into HTML5 persistant storage

Tags: html, storage, persistent

Is there any possible way to save an image, into HTML5 persistant storage? Doing all work required to break the image into - say, a byte array, client side?

Comment: I'm no expert in localstorage but wouldn't it be sounder to just store the url of the image in localstorage rather than the image itself? It seems to me it shouldn't be used that way, and I think you have very limited space for security reasons. EDIT: Apparently it's 5mb of storage.

Comment: how would i store the URL to the image if it hasnt been uploaded... This is for mobile devices by the way...

Comment: It is detailed here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840957/is-possible-to-read-image-from-remote-server-using-in-binary-mode-using-javascri

Answer (score 0):

Well its not so difficult. You need to convert your image into base64 string and then you can save the converted string into localstorage and also can set the source of your img tag

for example

localStorage.setItem('offlineimage',base64variable);

document.getElementById("myimage").src='data:image/png;base64,' + base64variable;

Thanks,
Khushwant Singh